# Retrieve distinct count DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, distinct, dynamodb-queries

I have a `DynamoDB` table to store activity in the session.

I'm trying to find distinct sessions from the table, but I didn't find anything in AWS document to how to retrieve distinct session ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB does not have a DISTINCT feature. You would need to design your table so that a query would return all the distinct session ids, then count them yourself.

This is the list of comparisons and functions available to you in a DynamoDB query: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

Comment: thanks for quick response. Is there any official document available, saying that DynamoDB does not have a DISTINCT feature?

Comment: Yes the link above has the list of all query operations and functions that are valid in DynamoDB. If you are coming from a SQL background, you will be disappointed